# Managing current offset in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, offset

I could not find any information in documentation about how kafka manages the current offset for a consumer. I guess consumer by default keeps the last offset read in memory and commits that either on an explicit call to `commitSync` or `commitAsync` or as per `enable.auto.commit` policy. Is this correct or am I missing something? If someone can point to a documentation or some reference to this aspect of offset management, it will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same question. Have you got the answer?

Answer (score 2):

A *consumer group*, is a set of consumers which are coordinated for consuming messages from topic(s). Now one of your Kafka brokers acts as the **group coordinator** which is responsible for coordinating all consumers belonging to that group.

Depending on the configuration of `enable.auto.commit` and they way you're handling offset management in your code, the will be committed and stored in a topic called `__consumer_offsets`.

---

If `enable.auto.commit` is set to `True` then the consumer's offset are periodically committed in the background. On the other hand, `commitSync()` and `commitAsync()` are blocking and non-blocking calls respectively that allow committing offsets manually. If you use one of `commitSync()` or `commitAsync()` it is recommended to set `enable.auto.commit` to `False`.

In the rare case where your policy `enable.auto.commit` is set to `True` but at the same time you make use of one of `commitSync()` or `commitAsync()` then offsets will be committed in both cases:

- Every time you call `commitSync()` or `commitAsync()`
- Every `N` ms where `N` is a configurable parameter (`auto.commit.interval.ms`)

---

When `enable.auto.commit` is set to `true`, then the largest offset is committed every `auto.commit.interval.ms` of time. However, this happens only whenever `poll()` is called. In every poll (`max.poll.interval.ms`), the `enable.auto.commit` is checked. Whenever you poll(), the consumer checks if it is time to commit the offset it returned in the last poll.

For more details, you can refer to [Confluent's documentation for Offset Management](https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/consumer.html#offset-management).

Comment: Thanks for the information. I am more interested in knowing about uncommitted (current) offset management (And the question is about that). Is that managed by consumer, if yes where and how?

Comment: @Aarkan I've edited my answer and included some more information.